# Invalid Filename, got xxxxxx but expected xxxxxxxx

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

My ClojureScript app is not compiling. It is throwing the error:

```sh
1 | (ns mock-file-system.api-service)
Invalid Filename, got mock_file_system/api-service.cljs but expected mock_file_system/api_service.cljs (or .cljc)
```

The calling namespace:

```clj
(ns mock-file-system.views
  (:require
   [re-frame.core :as re-frame]
   [reagent.core :as reagent]
   [mock-file-system.subs :as subs]
   [mock-file-system.node :as node]
   [mock-file-system.api-service :as api]
   ))
```

The required namespace:

```
(ns mock-file-system.api-service)
```

Thanks

Comment: What's the name of the file containing `mock-file-system.api-service`? The error suggest it's `api-service.cljs` but it should be `api_service.cljs`.

Comment: Thanks @Lee, it's `api-service.cljs`. I have searched the whole project for `api_service.cljs` but there is nothing. Don't know why it expects `api_service.cljs`.

Comment: So everything works when you rename the file?

Comment: Yeah :( Looks like you can't use dashes in file names but it converts underscores to dashes in the background.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can't use dashes in file names and it converts underscores to dashes in the background.

Fixed by renaming the file with an underscore.